# Ankh plugin for VS2008 problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

My ankhv plugin for vs2008 ceased to work.  I can't select in Tools->Options->Source Control, although there is an entry AnkhSVN in that combobox "Current source control plugin".   It continues to work with visual studio 2010.  I tried to run devenv /resetsettings with no help.  I also tried to repair (not reinstall) visual studio.  Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't tried unistalling AnkhSVN and reinstalling it, that's what I'd recommend first.

Comment: Did you check the add-in manager?

Comment: Where do I go finding that manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `devenv /setup` instead, if that doesn't work try reinstalling

Comment: Hey, that seemed to work, thanks.  T thought I'll have to go through painful scientific tries and after everything would fail I'd have to reinstall everything from scratch